# (Windows 10) Miniconda Pyopencl - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cl: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: windows, opencl, conda, miniconda, pyopencl

I've been working with pyopencl on my Macbook. I installed miniconda and installed pyopencl from there by using [these instructions](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html#installing-from-conda-forge).

On my Mac everything works fine, I can run a small example program and it works.

I then tried to use pyopencl on my Windows 10 desktop PC as that has a proper GPU (Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080TI) but I can't seem to get it it work with the same example program.

Like with the Mac I followed [these instructions](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html#installing-from-conda-forge) and installed miniconda and then pyopencl.

However when I run my example program I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\Exercises-Solutions-1.2.1\Exercises\Exercise03\Python>python vadd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vadd.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pyopencl as cl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import pyopencl.cltypes  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\cltypes.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyopencl.tools import get_or_register_dtype
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\tools.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pyopencl._cl import bitlog2  # noqa: F401
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cl: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

This is what I have installed via conda:

```
C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\Exercises-Solutions-1.2.1\Exercises\Exercise03\Python>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appdirs                   1.4.3                      py_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.6.20            hecda079_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.6.20        py38h9bdc248_2    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.0           py38h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003
conda                     4.8.5            py38h9bdc248_2    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py38h62dcd97_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
cryptography              2.9.2            py38h7a1dbc1_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.9                        py_1
intel-openmp              2020.1                      216
khronos-opencl-icd-loader 2020.06.16           h62dcd97_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                    16_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                    16_mkl    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                    16_mkl    conda-forge
mako                      1.1.3              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38hab1e662_2    conda-forge
menuinst                  1.4.16           py38he774522_0
mkl                       2020.1                      216
numpy                     1.19.2           py38hdf1ac2f_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1h               he774522_0    conda-forge
pip                       20.0.2                   py38_3
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38he774522_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0
pyopencl                  2020.2.2         py38hfd46600_1    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py38_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0
python                    3.8.3                he1778fa_0
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
pytools                   2020.4             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   227              py38he774522_1
requests                  2.23.0                   py38_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py38he774522_0
setuptools                46.4.0                   py38_0
six                       1.14.0                   py38_0
sqlite                    3.31.1               h2a8f88b_1
tqdm                      4.46.0                     py_0
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py38_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py38_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

I'm not sure If I'm missing something but it can't seem to find the DLL, so with that I tried ensuring my GPU drivers were up to date, that didn't work so then I tried to install the [Nvidia CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Once again this has no affect and the problem persists.

The only possible clue I have is that in the miniconda installation directory on my Macbook there is a OpenCl folder followed by a vendor folder that has an apple.icd file in.

```
miniconda3/etc/OpenCL/vendors/apple.icd.
```

However my miniconda install directory on my Windows PC seems to be missing that OpenCL folder, and by virtue the vendors folder and .icd file.

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\etc>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4E38-45B0

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\etc

12/10/2020  17:54    <DIR>          .
12/10/2020  17:54    <DIR>          ..
12/10/2020  17:54    <DIR>          fish
12/10/2020  18:04    <DIR>          profile.d
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  37,407,539,200 bytes free
```

This to me points to the cause of the issue, but I'm not sure. And even if it is I don't know what I'd need to do to produce this *.icd* file.

Any help would be appreciated.